# how to use append and after using if condition in jquery

Tags: jquery

How to simplify this code using jquery

[**FIddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/g2hrm9cb/4/)

```
$('#tableclick').click(function(){

if($('#tr_second').length == 0){ var adppend =$('#append_tr').append; } else { var adppend =$('#tr_second').append;  }

            adppend('<tr><td>test1</td><td>test2</td><td>test3</td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: Explain the question clearly

Comment: Can you please check out the code. You ill come to know.  What im trying to ask !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can use your condition. Here's a [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/g2hrm9cb/6/)

```
$('#tableclick').click(function() {
  var html = '<tr><td>test1</td><td>test2</td><td>test3</td></tr>';
  if (!$('#tr_second').length) {
    $('#append_tr').append(html);
  } else {
    $(html).insertAfter($('#tr_second'));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are simply wanting to copy the first row and add a clone of it on click of a button, if so, you could do it like this:

```js
$('#tableclick').click(function() {
  var $table = $('#my-table');
  var $tr = $table.find('tr').eq(0).clone();
  $table.append($tr);      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="my-table">
  <tr>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test2</td>
    <td>test3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test2</td>
    <td>test3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<a href="javascript:;" id="tableclick">click addon</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#tableclick').click(function(){

      if($('#tr_second').length == 0){
       $('#append_tr').append('<tr><td>test1</td><td>test2</td><td>test3</td></tr>'); 
      } 
      else { 
       $('#tr_second').append('<tr><td>test1</td><td>test2</td><td>test3</td></tr>');  
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="append_tr">
<tr>
<td>test1</td><td>test2</td><td>test3</td>
</tr>
<tr id="tr_second">
<td>test1</td><td>test2</td><td>test3</td>
</tr>
</table>

<a href="javascript:;" id="tableclick">click addon</a>
```

Not fully sure what you are looking for but, I think this is what your trying to achieve let me know if this helps.